# Changing MySQL DB encoding from Latin1_swedish to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, encoding, utf-8

I can't convert data from Latin1_swedish to UTF-8.

The application is based on Symfony2 and the database is MySQL.

I've already tried this query:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> CONVERT TO CHARACTER 
SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I would like a solution that does all the tables and columns, because MySQL database has 1000 tables.  If I had to modify them all manually it would take too long.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned "weird characters", I suspect that "changing from latin1 to utf8" is *not* the real task, but rather to fix up some kind of mess that happened during INSERTs.

There are about 5 cases to deal with.  We don't yet know which case you have.  Please provide

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a table that you are trying to change.
- `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some cell that has non-ascii text.

Let's review the attempts:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> CONVERT TO CHARACTER  SET utf8;
```

That assumes the table is declared to be latin1 and correctly contains latin1 bytes, but you would like to change it to utf8.  Since 'Ă' and 'Ĺ' do not exist in latin1, this ALTER feels very wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

is similar to the above, but works only one column at a time, and needs exactly the right stuff in the MODIFY clause.  Hence, it would be quite tedious.

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

merely sets the *default* `CHARACTER SET` for any new tables created in that `databasename`.  The word `DEFAULT` is optional.

`HEX('ĂĹ') = 'C482C4B9'` -- So it looks like you are working with some Eastern European language, perhaps using utf8, perhaps not.  Please provide further details.  What came before and after `Ă`?

The fix for the "weird characters" is probably in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll), but need details to point you directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change entire DB you should run this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it also does not do the trick. There are still weird characters such as 'Ă' or 'Ĺ'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```